Is the ring of formal power series over $\mathbb{C}$ an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$?
I am learning algebra and I got confused with the definitions. Suppose I have a ring $R$ and let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be abstract symbols. The ring of formal power series over $R$ is the ring $R[[X_{1},...,X_{n}]]$ defined by $R^{\mathbb{N}^{n}}$, the space of all functions $f: \mathbb{N}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$.
For $\alpha = (\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{n}) \in \mathbb{N}^{n}$, we write $f(\alpha) = f_{\alpha}$ and:
$$f = (f_{\alpha})_{\alpha} = \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^{n}}f_{\alpha}X^{\alpha}, \quad X^{\alpha} = X_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}\cdots X_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}$$
We can define multiplication and addition in a natural way:
$$f+g = \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^{n}}(f_{\alpha}+g_{\alpha})X^{\alpha} \quad \mbox{and} \quad fg = \sum_{\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{N}^{n}}f_{\alpha}g_{\beta}X^{\alpha+\beta}.$$
My question is simple. If I assume $R = \mathbb{R}$ or $R = \mathbb{C}$, it seems that the ring of formal power series becomes an algebra. Is this correct? Because I could not find anywhere where this information was confirmed.

Yes, it's an algebra over $R$ for any commutative ring $R$.

Apparently you didn't search in the Wikipedia page of formal power series...


I could not find anywhere where this information was confirmed.

This should be settled by your definition of "$F$-algebra."  For any field $F$ it usually goes something like:
"A ring $A$ is said to be an $F$ algebra if the center of $A$ contains a copy of $F$."  That is, there's a (unital) homomorphism from $F$ into $Z(A)$.
If you're talking about a commutative ring $A$, then you just need to contain a copy of $F$ sharing identity with $A$.
This should be abundantly clear for formal power series, because your copy of $F$ is just the subset of "constant" power series.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to PSQs & dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

@BillDubuque Which post are you thinking of as a duplicate?

It's a PSQ. That's a boilerplate comment for both PSQs & dupes. It's probably a dupe too - as you should know.
